# Odd error from exporting a Nest logger module from a shared package in monorepo (nestjs/core related?)

Tags: nestjs, monorepo, pnpm, turborepo

I've been dealing with this odd issue that happens in my turborepo using pnpm as the package manager,

The issue is that, when I import a shared logger module/service from my package to one of my nest microservices, this error is sometimes thrown when I start my service:

```
@../template-service:dev: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setContext')
@../template-service:dev:     at new ActionProxyService (C:\Users\Dareon\development\..\node_modules\.pnpm\file+packages+services+shared+action-service-shared_@nestjs+core@9.4.0\node_modules\@rewards\action-service-shared\src\action\modules\action-proxy\action-proxy.service.ts:24:17)
@../template-service:dev:     at Injector.instantiateClass (C:\Users\Dareon\development\rewards\node_modules\.pnpm\@nestjs+core@9.4.0_yn6wkbpy63w25j7vqpaxxesoiu\node_modules\@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:351:19)
```

I have absolutely no idea why this happens, and better yet, why it only happens sometimes?

When it does start happening, I have to delete all node modules and the pnpm-lock file, and reinstall/rebuild everything. Incredibly annoying.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? From the error message, it seems to relate to nestjs/core. Been going at it for hours now trying to solve this issue, and I would be so, so grateful if someone could help me!